# Как очистить текст от лишнего текста с обеих сторон от искомого текста?

Tags: c#

Используется С#. С сайта парсится текст, имеющий несколько вариантов:

**Вар 1**

FG654HGFH=FGJ6DJ131HDFHSFSGRv=http://site1.ru/jfd6oin/bfg654ryan-knight%3Futm_/te654DDFm%3D%26cid%3D1065

**Вар 2**

dfg6546sdgs=dgd646ttrdhx32gfh=http://site2.com/nhgh65h/bfg654ryan-kng654fight%/etesd6s5d4sdgs654DDFm%3D%2

**Вар 3**

dfh6565jrtu=u63mb2,1CjyttmKYU=http://site3.net/nsdxch6/bfg654vcvn-knsdsffbnht%/sdg987bn,uuio98ofp64utrury
 
Особые условия:

- домен site(1,2,3, …) - принят условно. Имя домена не имеет какой-либо тенденции и всегда разное;
- http://, может быть и https://

Как очистить текст, чтобы осталось, к примеру для http://site1.ru:

- http://site1.ru

или

- site1.ru

или

- Site1

При этом не привязываясь к имени домена, т.к. имена доменов не известны.

Comment: Вам наверное нужен класс System.Uri и к нему [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).

Comment: ели нужен только домен, то можно такую регулярку `http[s]?://\w+([.]\w+)+`, проверить можно тут http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант : )

```
        String str = @"FG654HGFH=FGJ6DJ131HDFHSFSGRv=http://site1.ru/jfd6oin/bfg654ryan-knight%3Futm_/te654DDFm%3D%26cid%3D1065";
        str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("://") + "://".Length);
        str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("/"));
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Выведет site1.ru

как ответ вариант с регуляркой от [rdom](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn) :

```
        String str = @"FG654HGFH=FGJ6DJ131HDFHSFSGRv=http://site1.ru/jfd6oin/bfg654ryan-knight%3Futm_/te654DDFm%3D%26cid%3D1065";
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"http[s]?://\w+([.]\w+)+");
        str = regex.Matches(str)[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Выведет: http://site1.ru

Comment: ответ из одной регулярки это не серьезно, поэтому висит в комментариях, можете дописать ее в свой, мне не жалко =)